# i have a problem with apt-get package manager

Tags: apt, permissions, virtualbox

```
root@imvenky-VirtualBox:~# /etc/apt/sources.list
-bash: /etc/apt/sources.list: Permission denied
```

then what can i do  for solve this

```
-bash /etc/apt/sources.list:Permission denied
```

Comment: Be careful. If you edit this file and mess it up, you'll have a real problem.

Comment: This seems like expected behavior. Root does indeed lack permission to execute the file (which is not intended to be executable, so does not have the executable bit set).  However, the error message seems a distraction from the real issue that I suspect you are asking about: What's really going on is that you made an error in your command - you didn't say what you wanted to happen to the file.

Comment: What are toy trying to achive?

Answer (score 5):

`/etc/apt/sources.list` is a path to a file named sources.list that is owned by root. It does not have permissions to opened by its default application which is Software & Updates. To do this it would be necessary for sources.list to have permissions to be executed as a program which it does not have.

To show the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` in the terminal run the following command:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

To edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` run the following command:

```
sudoedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

sources.list contains a list of the software sources/repositories in Ubuntu. It is a file of type Software sources list (text/x-apt-sources-list). A user can read and write the sources.list file by running `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` to read it and `sudoedit /etc/apt/sources.list` to write it.

Comment: +1, I learned about `sudoedit`

Answer (score 2):

you can see like that

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: By default `sources.list` is readable by anyone. Therefore, `sudo` isn't required with `cat`.

Comment: thank you for comment.